# In Prolog, need to create rule that returns a fact value. Currently only returning "true" and not the fact I need

Tags: prolog

I have a database of movies, release years, actors, directors. I need a query that returns the movie title if the year is greater than or equal to a given year entered by the user. The rule I created is below. M and Y are the movie title and year, and my parameter Y>=QYear should return only movie(M,Y) where the movie year is greater than or equal to the year entered by the user when invoking this rule, but instead, I am receiving output of only true when running the rule. Can anyone offer some guidance in what I'm doing incorrectly here?

movies_released_after(QYear, QMovie):- movie(M,Y), Y>=QYear.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have a variable named `QMovie` in the head of your clause (the part to the left of the `:-`, also known as the consequent) which is not used in the body of your clause (the part to the right of the `:-`, also known as the antecedent).

Instead try also using `QMovie` in the call to `movie/2`. This will cause `QMovie` to be unified with the value `movie/2` matches with.

Example:

```
movies_released_after(QYear, QMovie):- movie(QMovie,Y), Y>=QYear.
```

---

To learn more about Prolog you could try the introductory course available at [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)